# How to show sub category checkbox label in output div with remove icon and remove it on uncheck and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, frontend

[image: Please check image for more clarity]

I have a list of categories with sub categories. The user can select only one sub category from a category. I want to show the selected sub categories in an output div which has a remove icon, when clicking on remove it should be removed from the output list and also uncheck the same sub category.....

```
<div class="category-output">
   <ul>
   </ul>
</div>
<ul class="main-category-check">
     <li>
          <p>
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in categoryCheck"
                                                                name="season2" />
                                                            <span>Category 1</span>
                 </label>
        </p>
     <ul class="sub-category-check">
            <li>
                 <p>
                     <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 1</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in categoryCheck"
                                                                name="season2" />
                                                            <span>Category 2</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <ul class="sub-category-check">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 1</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in categoryCheck"
                                                                name="season2" />
                                                            <span>Category 3</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <ul class="sub-category-check">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 1</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

$('.sub-category-check li input').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents('p').parent().siblings().find('input').prop('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);
    var Check1 = $(this).siblings('span').text();
    $('.category-output ul').append('<li class="chip">' + Check1 + '<i class="close material-icons">close</i>' + '</li>');
  }
  else {
    $(this).parents('p').parent().siblings().find('input').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.category-output ul li').remove();
    //$('.category-output ul').append('<li class="chip">' + Check1 + '<i class="close material-icons">close</i>' + '</li>');
  }
}
);
```

Comment: please add your code JSFIDDLE and give link for that

Comment: You have not create .category-output div for append li so please create div for that .

Comment: oh sorry i have pasted wrong div here

Comment: so please  post your correct html div here

Comment: Updated the output div with correct class

Comment: Please check below answer .it is worked for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this script with this. it will work as per your requirement.

```js
function remove(a,b)
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-category-check");
 var r = x[b].querySelectorAll('input[name="season2"]');
 for(let j=0; j< r.length; j++){
    if(r[j].checked == true)
 {
  r[j].checked = false;
 }else
 {
  r[j].disabled = false;
 }
}
 $(a).parent('li').remove();
}
$('.sub-category-check li input').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents('p').parent().siblings().find('input').prop('checked', false).attr('disabled', true);
    var Check1 = $(this).siblings('span').text();
 var main_cat = $.trim($(this).parents().parent('li')[0]['children'][0].innerText);
 var cat = main_cat.replace(/ /g,"_"); 
 var cnt = cat.split("_");
 cnt = cnt[1] - 1;
 
    $('.category-output ul').append("<li class='chip_"+cat+"'>" + Check1 + "<i class='close material-icons' onclick='remove(this,"+cnt+")'>close</i>" + "</li>");
  }
  else {
    $(this).parents('p').parent().siblings().find('input').attr('disabled', false);
 var main_cat = $.trim($(this).parents().parent('li')[0]['children'][0].innerText);
 var cat = main_cat.replace(/ /g,"_"); 
    $('.category-output ul li.chip_'+cat).remove();
 
    //$('.category-output ul').append('<li class="chip">' + Check1 + '<i class="close material-icons">close</i>' + '</li>');
  }
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category-output">
   <ul>
   </ul>
</div>
<ul class="main-category-check">
     <li>
          <p>
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in categoryCheck"
                                                                name="season2" />
                                                            <span>Category 1</span>
                 </label>
        </p>
     <ul class="sub-category-check">
            <li>
                 <p>
                     <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 1</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in categoryCheck"
                                                                name="season2" />
                                                            <span>Category 2</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <ul class="sub-category-check">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 1</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in categoryCheck"
                                                                name="season2" />
                                                            <span>Category 3</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <ul class="sub-category-check">
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 1</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
                                                                        name="season2" />
                                                                    <span>Sub Category 2</span>
                                                                </label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
```

Comment: Hi Kaushal, Thanks for the answer, when we click on close icon its should uncheck related checkbox.

Comment: @Angaddy Ok i ll be back soon with your solution.

Comment: @Angaddy I update the answer as per your requirement . can you please check it work for you or not?